# Multilanguage table on Django, how to?

Tags: django, django-models, multilingual

I need to do a App with multilanguage support on Django but I can't figure out the best way of doing it.

Starting with a simple table like this one:

```
class Genders(models.Model):
    n_gender = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I need to have translations for the genders(male, female). What is the approach that I should have doing this task?

There are some apps when I could see how Django professionals do it?

Give me some clues.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

GENDERS = (('male', _('MALE')), ('female', _('FEMALE')))

class Genders(models.Model):
    n_gender = models.CharField(max_length= 60, choices= GENDERS)
```

and then translate them in the po files (see django docs for how to)
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I need them in the database because I will have some tables that need the "id" from "n_gender". Other words, I will have related tables using the "id" of "Genders". There is a way of doing it without database table? Best Regards,

Comment: Ignore that part I thought in the beginning the intention was to keep translations in the database :) Anyways, the answer is still ok for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Docs on Localization:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/

How To Add Localization to Your Django Project:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/i18n/

For an example, try looking at Pinax:
https://github.com/pinax/pinax

Template From Pinax using i18n:
https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/pinax/templates/default/account/email.html

Comment: Hey Mutant - You're right!  It's been over a year and FOSS projects change.  Nobody is going to monitor every link they post as a reference.  Next time, just go look up the new link and post it in the comments.
https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/0.7.X/pinax/templates/default/account/email.html